# android textview variable

Tags: java, android, variables, textview

Hello and sorry for my question, I study Java and now I am building a test program for android.

```
int a = 10;
```

with java I do: `System.out.println(a);` and this works perfectly.

By android I can't use `setText(a);` ?

I need to transform the variable to string?

thanks!

Pol

Answer (score 1):

Use [String.valueOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28int%29) to cast an integer value to String as:

```
int a=10;

text_Rate.setText(String.valueOf(a));
```

or you can add `""` with Integer for showing an Integer Value in TextView as:

```
int a=10;

text_Rate.setText(""+a);
```

Comment: @PolHallen : most welcome friend !!!:). if this answer help you then you can mark it as answer by clicking on RIGHT IMAGE on top upper side of answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should go through the Api docs of [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28int%29) first then you will understand the meaning of passing integer value in `setText()` method.

`setText()` is  an overloaded method.

If we pass integer value it will consider as for resource id which we declare in the value xml file(e.g. string.xml) so if you pass integer value it will try to find the resource id respect to the given integer which we pass and it wont find such resource matched with the given integer and app crashes.

Hope you have understand now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast your int to an String object

```
String s = Integer.toString(a);
view.setText(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println()` can except a String a argument. However `setText()` only takes a string as an argument. So if you would like to display a number as a String you can use the `String.valueOf()` method.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a `String` as argument on `setText()`, because `a` is an `int`. `System.out.println()` accepts everything, as one of the overloaded methods is `System.out.println(Object)`, but `setText()` does not have that. You can either use `String.valueOf(a)` or just use `setText("" + a)`.